# Reading id from URL

Tags: php, html, wamp, identifier

My question is pertaining to extracting information from the URL using PHP.
I've three pages in the website I am building

```
catalogues.html

form_userdata.php

mail.php
```

The schema is as follows. The user will choose a file to download from `catalogues.html`
for eg

```
a href="form_userdata.php?id=1026&name=Vibrating Feeder - Heavy duty -VFH" target="_blank"
```

This id & name will be passed to form_userdata.php and after entering the details in form_userdata.php page, the page passes control to `mail.php`, that will check if the fields are all true and valid.

My question is how can I use the ID & name specified in "a href" in my code?
I am passing the ID and name from `catalogues->form_userdata` and collecting it in mail.php

Thank you for your valuable input

Comment: when I add $id=$_POST['id']; at form_userdata, I get an error saying "undefined index: id"

Comment: @Vinne you already asked similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946060/help-using-the-id-tag-on-php

Comment: @vinner it's a GET variable, not a POST. try $_GET['id']

Comment: see your POST DATA by  `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I think you're talking about the fundamentals of PHP. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php. Then... format your questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @diEcho I removed it to avoid any confusion

Comment: @Vinner Best Option but not Best way `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = $id=$_GET['id'];

$_SESSION['name'] = $name=$_GET['name'];
```

this will pass the value of ID and Name to the next page. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can use sessions to store it when processing form_userdata.php and then use it in mail.php. That way you don't have to pass it in every URL.

Answer (score 1):

> when I add $id=$_POST['id']; at
>   form_userdata, I get an error saying
>   "undefined index: id"

That's quite logical, since you're passing them in the URI, and thus have to read them using $_GET in PHP, ie. do :

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
```

Comment: @wimvids I did some reading after seeing your comment, and found out to start a new session will make it work thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you may use `$_GET` to collect and pass variables

Answer (score 0):

You can access the named values in an URL (query string, query-info part) by using the $_GET superglobal. It will contain the value by it's name:

```
$_GET['id']
```

More information is in the the PHP manual: [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). That page is already pretty specific, I suggest you read this manual page as well: [Variables From External Sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) it more broadly describes how this works.

As input is very important in programming, it's really recommended to understand how it works so you can use the language for your needs more easily.

Comment: thanks the manual page Hakre I am starting to understand a bit more of PHP and the web